# Is backpropagation applied every layer the same?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, convolutional-neural-network, training, backpropagation

For example, I have layers that are pretrained. But while predicted, the loss is very high. But not because of pre-trained layers. Because of not pretrained layers. Will every layer be affected by backprop the same?

Comment: Not sure I get the question, you will need to freeze these layers as you train.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how you configure the training process:

You can, for instance, freeze the pretrained layers; this implies that only the not pretrained layers will be updated.

You can also set different learning rates to different layers, so that the pretrained layers are assigned a very small learning rate that allows them to be updated but not too fast.

Therefore, backpropagation is the same for all layers but the weight update strategy can be different.